# Between Vs Single condition

Tags: sql, db2, between

Why `between` operator takes long time to execute compared to single condition.

```
select a,b from table where trunc(a) between '2000-04-01' and '2016-03-31'

select a,b from table where trunc(a)>='2000-04-01'
```

First one takes so long to execute compare to second one, even there are same no of records.

Comment: You are filtering on a function result - trunc.  That will always take longer.  Maybe in this case it's being applied twice.  For greater performance use ` a >= '2000-04-01' and a <  '2016-04-01'`.

Comment: Showing the query plans will help to see what's wrong.

Comment: @ Dan Bracuk even I have removed trunc function but there is no improvement

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the first takes longer.  If you have run the queries only once, then perhaps it is because of a cold cache versus warm cache.

However, I think it is better to write the query without `between`:

```
where a >= '2000-04-01' and a < '2016-04-02'
```

This is better for two reasons.  First, the query can take advantage of an index (although that is probably not important because the date range is so wide).  In addition, this works regardless of whether the `a` has a time component.

Comment: thanks for quick response but there is no improvement

Comment: @HoneyBadger . . .  You were correct.  I fixed the typo.  Thank you.